# equal_range and 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, constants, multimap, equal-range

Here is this simple code

```
#include <map>

class MyMap : public std::multimap<int*, int*>
{
    public:
    void foo(const int* bar) const
    {
        equal_range(bar);
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyMap myMap;

    int number;
    myMap.foo(&number);

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile, and give the following error

```
error C2663: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::equal_range' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

I have seen many topic about this error, and it seems that it is a `const` issue. It compiles fine if I turn `foo(const int* bar)` into `foo(int* bar)`.

Problem is, I don't see how `foo` content is supposed to change anything to my MyMap object. `std::multimap` proposes a const version of `equal_range`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/

What is my problem?

Thank you

Comment: You do know that the most standard library classes are not designed to be inherited? For example, the [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/~multimap) is not `virtual`, so will not be called in the destruction of `MyMap` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of equal_range:

```
pair<const_iterator,const_iterator> equal_range (const key_type& k) const;
```

It expects a constant reference to `key_type`: `const key_type& k`.

What you were trying to supply was a pointer to a constant integer: `const int* bar`

Why doesn't this work even though both values are `const`?

- A constant reference to an integer `const int& foo` means that you cannot let `foo` refer to another integer, but it is allowed to change the value of the referenced integer.
- A pointer to a constant integer `const int* foo` means that you can let `foo` point to another integer, but you cannot change the value of the integer it points to.

What the map actually expects is a `const int*& k`, but the map will automatically convert this if you supply a `int*` only (without the `const`).

[Edit]

Also note that a `MyMap` object still cannot be changed by your `foo` function even if you change `const int*` to `int*` as there still is another const at the end of your `foo` function. This const at the very end declares the function as constant meaning that it cannot modify the current object in which it is executed. If it was trying to modify it or call anything that could potentially modify it, you would get a compiler error. (Disclaimer: There are ways to modify a class from within a const function anyway but that's another topic.)

Comment: This is subtle, but I think I get the idea.

What I would like is to make `key_type='const int*'`, but since const principle is not part of the type, it isn't possible to do that.
Problem with using a simple `int*` is that the function won't guarantee anymore that it doesn't change the pointed value. How should I deal with that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If fact the right compiler message can give you the answer. For one of the two overloads (the `const` one):

```
/usr/local/include/c++/v1/map:1836:41: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const int *')
      would lose const qualifier
```

`const int*` is a pointer to a `const int`. The method expects a `const key_type&`, i.e. `const int*&` argument, that is a `const` reference to a (non-`const`) `int*`.

When confused, prefer to write `const int*` as `int const*`, which is the same thing. Then you'll see the difference to `const int*&` more clearly.

For your code to work, use `int*` instead of `const int*`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem has to do with the mismatch on the `key_type`.
On one hand you have a multimap where `key_type=int*` while on the other hand you are passing a `key_type=const int*` thus attempting to drop the const qualifier on the `key_type`. I was confused by this too because I was expanding the `key_type` in my mind to get `const int*&` which should be compatible. However, the mismatch happens earlier on the `key_type` itself. At least that's the only logical explanation I could think of.

My suggestion would be to make the `key_type` `const int*` and keep your function parameter as is. After all, why would you need a pointer to a mutable value as a key to a map ?